# Function in react-table columnDef shows empty value for property passed from parent component

Tags: reactjs, sharepointframework, react-table-v8

I am trying to build a CRUD app using react and tanstack table v8 within sharepoint framework using React as the framework. I am running into an issue outlined below.

I have to do an API call to sharepoint to get the Digest Key so I can write to the list. This works and I pass that down to the table component code file below. I can see in my console that both the parent component and table component do have the value of the key when the web part loads.

The issue I am running into is when I pass requestDigest into the onClick of the buttons in the columnDef object array the console shows it as empty. I have another component file for a form that writes to the list that they key shows fine and the POST works. So I am guessing it is some sort of scope issue but I am at a loss as I have even tried making the buttons components and passing the components into columnDef but that did not work either.

Code for table component below

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import "./table.css";
import {
  useReactTable,
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  createColumnHelper
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
//import { columnDef } from "./columns";
import dataJSON from "./data.json";
import SharePointForm from "./SubmitForm";

const sharepoint_url = '[redacted]/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'TanStackTableData\')/items';

const BasicTable = ({requestDigest}) => {
  console.log(requestDigest, "FROM TABLE COMPONENT") // This shows in my console

  const updateData = async (id, requestDigest) => {
    console.log("Update Key:", requestDigest);
    const data = {
      __metadata: { type: 'SP.Data.TanStackTableDataListItem' },
      Title: SharePointForm.firstName,
      first_name: SharePointForm.firstName,
      last_name: SharePointForm.lastName,
    };

    fetch(`[redacted]/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'TanStackTableData\')/items(${id})`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "If-Match": "*",        
        "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
        "X-RequestDigest": requestDigest
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      fetchData();
      console.log('Data successfully added:', data);
      setFirstName('');
      setLastName('')
      // Optionally, update state or perform actions on successful addition of data
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error adding data:', error);
      // Handle error scenario
    });
  };

  const columnDef = [
    {
        accessorKey: 'ID',
        header: 'ID'
    },
    {
        accessorKey: 'first_name',
        header: 'First Name'
    },
    {
        accessorKey: 'last_name',
        header: 'Last Name'
    },
    {
        header: "Actions",
        accessorKey: "ID",
        cell: (cell) => {
            return (
              <>
                <button onClick={() => handleButtonClick(cell.row.original?.ID, setFirstNameUpdate, setLastNameUpdate, requestDigest)}>Edit</button>
                <button onClick={() => updateData(cell.row.original?.ID, requestDigest)}>Update</button>
              </> 
            );
        }
    }
  ]

  const columnHelper = createColumnHelper();

  const [firstNameUpdate, setFirstNameUpdate] = useState('');
  const [lastNameUpdate, setLastNameUpdate] = useState('');

  const fetchUpdateDataFromSharePoint = async (id) => {
    console.log(requestDigest, "Initial Data Grab")
      try {
     
          const response = await fetch(`[redacted]/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'TanStackTableData\')/items(${id})`, {
              method: 'GET',
              headers: {
              // Include headers as needed for authentication
              'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         
              },
          });
          const data = await response.json();
          return data; 
          } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
          throw error;
          }
      };

  const handleButtonClick = async (ID, setFirstNameUpdate, setLastNameUpdate, requestDigest) => {
      // Handle button click event here, using data from the row if needed
      console.log('Button clicked for row:', ID);
      // Perform your desired action...
      try {
          // Fetch data from SharePoint based on the ID
          const data = await fetchUpdateDataFromSharePoint(ID);
          console.log(data)
      
       
          setFirstNameUpdate(data.d.first_name); 
          setLastNameUpdate(data.d.last_name); 
          console.log("From grab update data", requestDigest);
      } catch (error) {
      
      console.error('Error handling button click:', error);
      }
  };

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      // Fetch data from SharePoint list
      const response = await fetch(sharepoint_url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          // Include headers as needed for authentication
          'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });
  
      if (response.ok) {
        const result = await response.json();
        setListData(result.d.results); 
      } else {
        // Handle error responses
        console.error('Failed to fetch data:', response.statusText);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  
  const [listData, setListData] = useState([])
  const [columnDefFinal, setColumnDefFinal] = useState(columnDef)
  //let listData = [];  

  console.log(listData);

//   const finalData = React.useMemo(() => listData, []);
//   console.log('final', finalData);
//   const finalColumnDef = React.useMemo(() => columnDef, []);

  

  const tableInstance = useReactTable({
    columns: columnDefFinal,
    data: listData,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
  });

  console.log("hello");
  console.log("test", tableInstance.getHeaderGroups());
  
  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <thead>
          {tableInstance.getHeaderGroups().map((headerEl) => {
            return (
              <tr key={headerEl.id}>
                {headerEl.headers.map((columnEl) => {
                  return (
                    <th key={columnEl.id} colSpan={columnEl.colSpan}>
                      {columnEl.isPlaceholder
                        ? null
                        : flexRender(
                            columnEl.column.columnDef.header,
                            columnEl.getContext()
                          )}
                    </th>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {tableInstance.getRowModel().rows.map((rowEl) => {
            return (
              <tr key={rowEl.id}>
                {rowEl.getVisibleCells().map((cellEl) => {
                  return (
                    <td key={cellEl.id}>
                      {flexRender(
                        cellEl.column.columnDef.cell,
                        cellEl.getContext()
                      )}
                    </td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <SharePointForm fetchData={fetchData} firstNameUpdate={firstNameUpdate} lastNameUpdate={lastNameUpdate} requestDigest={requestDigest} />
    </>
  );
};

export default BasicTable;
```